# Textbox letter content check

Tags: c#

I'm writing a C# project,
One of my needs is to expose button when TextBox (not dynamic) have more then 1 letter, As long as i know changes (which includes functions activation) will happen only between postacks.
Is there any possibilty to check the Texbox letter content without using postback (Includes skip on page load function).

Thanks Ahead.

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: Assuming this is a Webforms project, if you want an action to happen on the server you need the postbacks (or AJAX).  If you want the logic to happen in the browser you need javascript

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any possibilty to check the Textbox letter content without
>   using postback (Includes skip on page load function).

Assuming you are using ASP.NET Web Form, you could call **WebMethod** via **Ajax**.

[image]

After posting back to server via Ajax,

[image]

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" 
      Inherits="WebApplication1.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" />
        <button type="button" onclick="postData();">Post Data</button>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function postData() {
                var data = { text: $('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').val() };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/default.aspx/postdata") %>',
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function (msg) {
                        $('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').val(msg.d);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Code Behind

```
using System;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string PostData(string text)
        {
            return text + DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```